# Count items in new array map

Tags: javascript

I've got a large array which I'm then pulling out the unique key/value pairs for certain fields like this:

```
    let dropdown = {};
    dropdown.make = [...new Set(vehicles.map((item) => item.Make))];
    dropdown.model = [...new Set(vehicles.map((item) => item.Model))];
    return dropdown;
```

This works correctly and will return all the unique values of make and model within a new object. How can I also have it return the count against each item?

So if the dropdown.model returns an array with 3 items, is it possible to get the total count next to each of the three items to see how many records there were in the original array for each of the three items?

Currently, the output looks something like this:

```
{
  "dropdown": {
    "make": [
      "Kia"
    ],
    "model": [
      "Carens",
      "Ceed"
    ],
    "colour": [
      "Silver",
      "White",
      "Black"
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the best way of outputting so the format is similar to this:

```
{
  "dropdown": {
    "make": [
      {
        "name": "Kia",
        "count": 5
      }
    ],
    "model": [
      {
        "name": "Carens",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Ceed",
        "count": 3
      }
    ],
    "colour": [
      {
        "name": "Silver",
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Black",
        "count": 3
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you `await`ing an array?

Comment: @SLaks - I'm not, was a bad copy and paste, edited above to reflect

Comment: Your question is quite simple - you have an input data structure, and you want an output data structure. All that's required is a single function to do that. However, you have'nt actually given us the input data structure, and you haven't given us the function that gives you your current output. Doing those two things would help us help you much better

Comment: Sample input data format - https://pastebin.com/ZGF1nHgQ

Comment: @TamoorMalik that's a good start, but on stackoverflow there's a general policy of [minimum reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In the future, your example data set should preferrably not include dozens of fields that aren't relevant to your question. At the moment, your example dataset includes dozens of lines we don't care about, but only 2 vehicles -- a better example would be more vehicles, and none of the extra data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let vehicles = [
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'b'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'y', model: 'c'},
  {make: 'y', model: 'c'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'd'},
  {make: 'z', model: 'd'},
] 

let makes = Object.values(vehicles.reduce((makes, {make}) => {
  makes[make] = makes[make] || {name: make, count: 0};
  makes[make].count++;
  return makes;
}, {}));

let models = Object.values(vehicles.reduce((models, {model}) => {
  models[model] = models[model] || {name: model, count: 0};
  models[model].count++;
  return models;
}, {}));

let dropdown = {makes, models};

console.log(dropdown);
```

Edit, generic function:

```js
let vehicles = [
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'b'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'y', model: 'c'},
  {make: 'y', model: 'c'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'd'},
  {make: 'z', model: 'd'},
];

let vehicleReduce = (vehicles, key) =>
    Object.values(vehicles.reduce((acc, vehicle) => {
        let value = vehicle[key];
        acc[value] = acc[value] || {name: value, count: 0};
        acc[value].count++;
        return acc;
    }, {}));

let makes = vehicleReduce(vehicles, 'make');
let models = vehicleReduce(vehicles, 'model');
let dropdown = {makes, models};
console.log(dropdown);
```

And lastly, this is how you can destructure dynamic keys:

```js
let key = 'make';
let {[key]: value} = {make: 'x'};
console.log(value, '===', 'x');
```

```js
let vehicles = [
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'b'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'y', model: 'c'},
  {make: 'y', model: 'c'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'a'},
  {make: 'x', model: 'd'},
  {make: 'z', model: 'd'},
];

let vehicleReduce = (vehicles, key) =>
    Object.values(vehicles.reduce((acc, {[key]: value}) => {
        acc[value] = acc[value] || {name: value, count: 0};
        acc[value].count++;
        return acc;
    }, {}));

let makes = vehicleReduce(vehicles, 'make');
let models = vehicleReduce(vehicles, 'model');
let dropdown = {makes, models};
console.log(dropdown);
```

Comment: You're destructuring the wrong property in `models`.

Comment: @junvar - Assume rather than having duplicate code if I wanted to pull 10 different attributes it'd be better to have a generic function for the reduce and then loop through all the properties from vehicles that would want to be included?

Comment: A generic function sounds like a good idea. Take a stab at it, and if you get stuck, ask for help.

Comment: I thought i'd be able to convert it into it's own function and pass in the dataset and a key but the key doesn't appear to be used - https://pastebin.com/wMWkrDtd

Comment: Your snippet is almost correct! You're trying to destructive on a dynamic key. This is kind of tricky (though possible), and best to avoid for simplicity. I'll update my answer to tweak your snippet to use `key` properly.